# Probability of obtaining the word

Tags: probability

a word 'PAPAGAY' is formed by letters of an alphabetic section. Then cards with letters are well mixed and any four of them are drawn one after another in succession and arranged in a row. what is probability of obtaining the word 'PAPA' by this procedure.? 
anybody can you please tell me how to solve this problem. it would be great help thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I would say

$P(PAPA)= P(1 = P)\cdot P(2 = A) \cdot P(3 = P) \cdot P(4 = A) = \frac{2}{7}\cdot\frac{3}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{70}$